# Materialize Datepicker Only Update if Done button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I am using the materializecss Datepicker (https://materializecss.com/pickers.html), and this seems like it should be really straightforward so I'm losing my mind a bit over it. Put simply, I'm trying to trigger an event only if the "Ok" button is clicked, but cannot identify that in the onClose() function provided. If I try to listen for the specific button click, I lose all that comes with the onClose() function (which nicely packages up all the info I need on that event).

Is there any way, with the onClose() function, that I can identify which button caused that onClose() to fire?

I'm admittedly a novice when it comes to javascript and jquery, so any help is appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" value="8/4/2018" job="533">
```

**Javascript Code to initialize the datepicker**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      "format": "m/d/yyyy",
      onClose() {
          // only do something if this was fired from the "Done" button
      }
    })
});
```

**Datepicker modal created**

```
<div class="modal datepicker-modal" id="modal-a5a43c91-2426-5565-c216-1d8ccd0cfc1d" tabindex="0">
    <div class="modal-content datepicker-container">
        <div class="datepicker-date-display">
            <span class="year-text">
            </span>
            <span class="date-text">
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="datepicker-calendar-container">
            <div class="datepicker-calendar">
            </div>
            <div class="datepicker-footer">
                <button class="btn-flat datepicker-clear waves-effect" style="visibility: hidden;" type="button">
                </button>
                <div class="confirmation-btns">
                    <button class="btn-flat datepicker-cancel waves-effect" type="button">
                        Cancel
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn-flat datepicker-done waves-effect" type="button">
                         Ok
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean the "Ok" button instead of the "Done" button? I can't see a "Done" button in your code, so I'll just assume you mean the "Ok" button.

Comment: _"If I try to listen for the specific button click, I lose all that comes with the onClose() function (which nicely packages up all the info I need on that event)."_

Are you sure you can't use just a regular `click` handler?  What specifically do you need from the `onClose` event?

Comment: @david My apologies, I did mean the "Ok" button.

Comment: @David The specific piece I'm looking for is the `job` id that sits with the datepicker input. If I just listen to the button click, I don't get that job id easily, and the button is generated dynamically so I also cannot easily assign the job id to the button itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code below can help you get the right button you want to do some stuff with it. Add 2 listeners to the done and cancel buttons of that opened modal right in onOpen(), and remove listeners onClose().
This will work for you.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function Cancel() {
            if(!this.hasEvent) {
                this.hasEvent = true;
                console.log('Clicked on cancel btn:', this.cancelBtn);
            }
        }
        function Done() {
            if(!this.hasEvent) {
                this.hasEvent = true;
                console.log('Clicked on done btn:', this.doneBtn);
            }
        }
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            "format": "m/d/yyyy",
            onOpen: function(e) {
                var that = this;
                that.hasEvent = false;
                this.cancelBtn.addEventListener('click', Cancel.bind(that))
                this.doneBtn.addEventListener('click', Done.bind(that))
            },               
            onClose: function(e) {
                var that = this;
                this.cancelBtn.removeEventListener('click', Cancel.bind(that))
                this.doneBtn.removeEventListener('click', Done.bind(that))
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, SaJadJaf! However, I think this still presents the issue that I'm getting that `data-whitch` attribute regardless of whether I click the `Cancel` button or the `Ok` button. Or am I misunderstanding your recommendation?

Comment: Hi, sorry about that, I think that confused you a little. I edited my answer above. see the last part again. hope that help you.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, but I think we're still talking about different things. I want to know _which_ button caused the `onClose()`, I'm able to find the buttons just fine. I want to see, when the `onClose()` occurs, what action was responsible for that (whether it's clicking the `.cancel-button` or `.ok-button`). Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh, man. I have your answer. I'm sorry, I was too busy, couldn't get back to you sooner. Anyway, I wrote another answer for you.

Comment: I edited my answer (removed all previous details) to clear it out.

Comment: Love this answer! This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. I'll try this out!

Answer (score 0):

First you can initialize the `Datepicker` just by using `vanillaJS`, then if you check `materialize.css` file then you'll find the `class name` of Ok button, that is, `.datepicker-done`. You can attach addEventListener to this button and call any function you want.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var elems = document.querySelector('.datepicker'); 
    var instance = M.Datepicker.init(elems);
    var doneBtn = document.querySelector('.datepicker-done');
    doneBtn.addEventListener('click', callThis); //Attaching a 'click' event to done button

    function callThis() {
        console.log('Done Button clicked only!'); //Checking the done button click
        console.log(elems.getAttribute('job')); //To get the job attribute value
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Germa, and my apologies for the delayed response! I think this is the right idea, but when I try to bind addEventListener to doneBtn it doesn't seem to be working. When I click the `Ok` button, it doesn't trigger the callThis event

Comment: I think I see what's happening here, and I think it's due to a poor explanation on my part (apologies again!). 

This works for a _single_ datepicker, but I have a page with many datepickers. Would querySelectorAll and a forloop work instead?

Answer (score 0):

All of the responses were extremely helpful in figuring this out, thank you to those who contributed!

I don't know if this is the most elegant solution, but it is working for me. I kept the jquery call to initialize all of the datepickers on the page, then added the event listeners with a `forEach` loop. To get the values I wanted, I had to do that crazy looking series of `.parent()` calls, but it consistently gets me the right information. Hopefully this helps someone dealing with the same issue in the future (or it can help someone else provide a more effective answer!).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      "format": "m/d/yyyy",
    })
  });
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var doneBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker-done');
    doneBtn.forEach(function(elem) {
        elem.addEventListener('click', callThis)
    });
  });

function callThis() { 
    var update = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().siblings('input');
    // do the thing I want with that input value
};
```

Comment: If this answers your question, then you should select this as accepted answer by clicking on the green check in the left of your answer and vote up the answers that were useful to find this out.